# GIS data for Keystone XL Pipeline?

Tags: geospatial, energy

Does anyone know a source for the GIS / spatial dataset of the proposed Keystone XL Pipeline Route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://keystone.steamingmules.com/maps/keystone-xl-google-earth-downloads/

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31261/finding-shapefiles-of-pipeline-data

There is a long list that you can get from google search : https://www.google.com/#q=keystone+pipelines+gis+data+download